# Moshi generic adapter for all retrofit calls

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

Is it possible to have "generic" adapter for all retorfit calls for example my reponse is always nested in data field example:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Hey",
            "last_name": "Test"
        },
        {
            "name": "Hey",
            "last_name": "Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

So currently for only one call i have Adapter for Moshi as following:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class WrappedPersonsList

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class PersonList(var data: List<PersonDto>)

class CustomJsonAdapter {
    @WrappedPersonsList
    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(json: PersonList): List<PersonDto> {
        return json.data
    }

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(@WrappedPersonsList value: List<PersonDto>): PersonList {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
}
```

So if i add another call with same nested level "data" but different fields i would again have to create adapter with new types? Or is it possbile to make it generic so i always skip directly to data field?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two types of data `Person` data like now and `"Cat"` data for another.

The problem is if you can't tell the difference between  `Person` data and `Cat` data, than neither can your adapter but if you can already tell what it is from an internal data field, like "last_name"
Then you can use this to make a `Map` and deserialize it from there.
https://newbedev.com/how-to-deserialize-generic-types-with-moshi

If you have access to the API call you could change `data` to `person_data` and when cats come along you can have `cat_data`. *(This may save you some future headaches)* Then you could quite easily tell the difference between a `Person` and a `Cat`.